# How to sum or add two values by using SQL command

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to add them together?
Need to be in vb.net

Two value statement as below:

```
(SELECT SUM(ChildName) FROM Child SA WHERE SA.Name=A.Name AND SA.Health_Status=1 AND SA.Parrent_ID IS NOT NULL) AS Present_CHILD

(SELECT SUM(LATE_COMING_CHILD) FROM LATE_COME SB WHERE SB.Name=A.Name) AS LATE_CHILD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use what is referred to as a "scalar subquery":

```
select (select Name from table1) + (select Name from table2)
```

Comment: assuming those tables contain only 1 row.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, if Table1 and Table2 have a reference that relate them to each other, you can add their fields. The best way is defining a foreign key for one of them, referring to primary key of other table.

For example you can define a new column in Table2 named Table1Id, and rewrite the query as bellow:

```
SELECT Table1.Name+Table2.Name
FROM Table2
  INNER JOIN Table1 
  ON Table2.Table1Id=Table1.Id
```

If there is no relation between Table1 and Table2, so there is no meaning for adding fields of these tables.

In the edited situation, the query may be as follows:

```
SELECT SA.ChildName+' '+SB.LATE_COMING_CHILD AS AllNames
FROM LATE_COME SB 
  INNER JOIN Child SA
  ON SB.ChildId=SA.Id
WHERE
  SA.Health_Status=1 
  AND 
  SA.Parrent_ID IS NOT NULL
```

I don't understand why all names of a person must use in one filed!
Additionally I suggest you learn SQL from scratch...

Comment: @Armir Zojaji i have update the question, if use inner join , i need to add them and get the result by using vb.net

Comment: @Andrew, I edited the Answer, but it is no good idea to use Name as foreign and primary key.